# Android - ArrayList и OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, java, исключения, файлы

Здравствуйте!Пишу плеер, и одна из его функций - сканирование заданной папки и её подпапок на наличие .mp3 файлов с помощью рекурсии (мне её предложили в прошлом вопросе). Потом полученные данные заносятся в ArrayList<HashSet<String, String>>. Но при заполнении списка мне выкидывает OutOfMemoryException. Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с решением этой проблемы!
Вот полный код сканера:

---

```
public class SongsProvider
{
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

public SongsProvider()
{}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(File dir) //в качестве пути передаю /sdcard1/Музыка/ (MicroSD-флешка)
{
    for (File file1 : dir.listFiles())
    {
        if (file1.isDirectory()) songsList.addAll(getPlayList(file1));
    }

    if (dir.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0)
    {
        for (File file2 : dir.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()))
        {
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song.put("songTitle", file2.getName().substring(0, (file2.getName().length() - 4)));
            song.put("songPath", file2.getAbsolutePath());
            songsList.add(song);
        }
    }
    return songsList;
}

class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter
{
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
    {
        return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
    }
}
```

}

---

Comment: Поздравляю! Вы смогли запутать простейший пример рекурсии))) Послать бы Вас читать Хорстмана ...

Comment: @woesss, запутать-то запутал, я эт могу! А вот решить проблему - нет) вот и прошу помощь))

Comment: Как говорил мой старшина: "Не впихуй невпихуемое)))"
Сначала получите список ФАЙЛОВ - потом отфильтруйте ЕГО по расширению(то есть разделите на два метода) - и да придёт оптимизация с пониманием последовательностей)))